# How do I install libobjc-9-dev on Ubuntu for ARM?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gcc, arm

I'm trying to install Clang on Ubuntu 20.04 for ARM, which needs `libobjc-9-dev`. The Ubuntu 20.04 ARM repositories only have a version that needs GCC 9.3 but I currently have GCC 9.4 (trying to downgrade to GCC 9.3 leads to apt prompting me to uninstall x11 and xwayland).

I'm looking for a way to just grab a newer `libobjc-9-dev` but I can't find any links. I found [this official website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/arm64/libobjc-9-dev/download), and it says "You can download the requested file [...] at any of these sites:" but there are no sites listed after the colon. I also found [this unofficial site](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/universe/base/libobjc-9-dev) and all the links for deb packages are for x86. The third link on Google is for another unofficial site that [seems to have it](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-proposed-universe-arm64/libobjc-9-dev_9.4.0-1ubuntu1%7E20.04_arm64.deb.html) except that the link for "Binary Package" points to an [x86_64 package from Ubuntu](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-9/libobjc-9-dev_9.4.0-1ubuntu1%7E20.04_amd64.deb). If I manually change "amd64" to "arm64" then the link doesn't work.

How do I download and install Clang and `libobjc-9-dev`? I've tried `sudo apt install` and the first three links on Google yet I'm unable to find an ARM version of `libobjc-9-dev` version `9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04` (to match Ubuntu's GCC version).

For the record, here is the message when trying to install `libobjc-9-dev` on Ubuntu 20.04 for ARM:

```
$ sudo apt install libobjc-9-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libobjc-9-dev : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgcc-9-dev (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
```

Comment: A quick look shows *focal* or 20.04 should have available `libobjc-9-dev | 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 | focal-updates/universe    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which isn't the version you're using; you appear to have upgraded to *testing* or -proposed package `libobjc-9-dev | 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04  | focal-proposed/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` thus your issue. Why did you add the proposed/testing package(s), as if you remove them, you'll possibly be returning to the issue that had you install *proposed* packages in the first place.

Comment: @guiverc I didn't add proposed/testing packages. This is mostly a clean install of Ubuntu, no extra repositories or special settings. I did do a few things like `sudo apt install build-essential`. GCC 9.4 is just the version that Ubuntu gave me. If I try to downgrade it to GCC 9.3 it tries to remove x11.

Comment: When I downloaded Ubuntu I found the daily build [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/). Is it possible that these daily builds have the proposed/testing packages by default? If so, where can I get a non-daily version of Ubuntu 20.04 for ARM? I can't find any other download links for it.

Comment: The *daily* images are for QA-testing of 20.04.4 which isn't scheduled for release until [10th February 2022](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule)  Released images are found at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.3/release/  (you'll see a link for arm builds)

Comment: @guiverc I don't see any ISOs for the desktop version of Ubuntu at that link. It's all server versions.

Comment: Sorry I just checked *arm64* was there, but there was no mention of Server/Desktop in your question so I didn't look for that. I do not use it myself do don't have reason to remember what's available easily sorry (`desktopify` converts a server image to desktop for raspberry.pi; created by a prior lead of Ubuntu Desktop for Canonical https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I did mention X11 and Wayland in my post though.

Comment: I've seen many questions here asking why users have X11/Wayland installed on their servers...  They can be installed because of using desktop applications commonly used for image conversion on servers; some built in *deb* packages have *depends* rules for X11 or Wayland... so those packages can exist on servers too.  It's best if you're explicit.